# Tablesize is different although Table DDL and data is exactly same(Teradata)

Tags: teradata, database-administration

I encountered very strange issue in teradata today.I created one table from another table using following syntax:

```
create table a.xyz as a.abc with data;
```

so obviously xyz will be created exactly same as abc(including column attributes). Also data will be same. However if I execute query to get size of that table using allspace or tablesize, new table is taking more size than original table? May I know why it should be the case? I checked skew factor as well for curiosity, surprisingly skew factor of new table was less(ideally it should be same because same PI and same data). abc having UPI and one column got column level compression as well, but of course both these attributes copied in new table as well.

May I know what is happening here?

Comment: Is it the same PI? I don't see you setting PI here in your `CREATE TABLE` statement. [see here for defaults used](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1184_111A/Create_Table-Details.012.100.html). It seems the default PI is better than you original table's PI since it has better skew. Which may explain the size difference as well.

Comment: In teradata if you use above syntax, same PI will be copied in new table.

Comment: How much difference? The source table might have Block Level Compression applied.

Comment: @dnoeth one is 100mb other one is 600mb. How to check if BLC applied on source?  I don't have access on any utiltiy(DBA utilties).

Comment: Afaik end users can't get that info before TD15.10 (then there's `BLCCompRatio` in `dbc-StatsV` and more details in `SHOW STATS VALUES`). But a 6:1 difference seems to indicate BLC.